# In Debye model, If rigid coupling between layers by each atom is exist, the soundwave can be propagated to other layers?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, phonons

[image]

[image]

My question is mainly related to (a).

What I`m trying to say is that considering the specimen is constructed to layer by layer and each atom on a layer is rigidly coupled with atom of up and down layer.
Then Can phonon vibration(in Debye model, as soundwave) go through up and down? or not? and why?

Should I do consider about transverse and longitudinal directions of the soundwave?

this problem is in "Introduction to solid state physics 8th" of Charles Kittel, Chapter 5 Problem 4.